Question on whether the ListModel attribute exists in QML
In actual development, I defined a ListModel where each element has different attributes. Some elements do not have the power attribute, some elements do not have the wavelength attribute, and some elements do not have the moduleId attribute. I wanted to use globalModel. get (currentIndex). property===undefined to determine whether a certain attribute exists, but all failed. The following are the issues I have discovered:
When the property of ListElement does not exist, it cannot be compared with undefined

If this property exists in other ListElements and is of numerical type, it defaults to 0 instead of undefined
If this property exists in other ListElements and is of string type, then it is undefined

import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListModel {
        id: globalModel
        ListElement { moduleId: "module1"; power: 30; wavelength: 650 }
        ListElement { moduleId: "module2"; power: 50; wavelength: 700 }

        ListElement { moduleId: "module3"; wavelength: 500 }
        ListElement { moduleId: "module4"; power: 80 }
        ListElement { moduleId: "module5"; power: 80 }
        ListElement { moduleId: "module6" }
        ListElement { }
    }

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox
        model: globalModel
        currentIndex: 0
        textRole: "moduleId" 
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            // No matter how I switch, the output is always false
            console.log(globalModel.get(currentIndex).power === undefined, globalModel.get(currentIndex).wavelength === undefined)
            
            //When I switched to the last one, it output undefined 0 0, which means the last ListElement's moduleId field is undefined! But the power and wavelength attributes are 0, so logically they should also be undefined!         
            var currentItem=globalModel.get(currentIndex)
            console.log(currentItem.moduleId,currentItem.power,currentItem.wavelength)
        }
    }
}


To use a ListModel effectively, all your records must be well defined, and, in particular, the first record inserted serves as a template for other records to follow. This does not fit your use case at all. You have several alternatives:

Hybrid ListModel + data dictionary,

    ListModel {
        id: globalModel
        ListElement { moduleId: "module1" }
        ListElement { moduleId: "module2" }
        ListElement { moduleId: "module3" }
        ListElement { moduleId: "module4" }
        ListElement { moduleId: "module5" }
        ListElement { moduleId: "module6" }
        ListElement { moduleId: "" }
    }
    property var attr: ({
        "module1": { power: 30, wavelength: 650 },
        "module2": { power: 50, wavelength: 700 },
        "module3": { wavelength: 500 },
        "module4": { power: 80 },
        "module5": { power: 80 }
    })

This makes your ListModel and your ComboBox can react to incremental updates. As for your attributes, you can access them from your delegate via attr[comboBox.currentText].

Array

    property var globalModel: ([
        { moduleId: "module1", power: 30, wavelength: 650 },
        { moduleId: "module2", power: 50, wavelength: 700 },
        { moduleId: "module3", wavelength: 500 },
        { moduleId: "module4", power: 80 },
        { moduleId: "module5", power: 80 },
        { moduleId: "module6" },
        { }
    ])

The above would give you full control over the attributes via modelData however, you will lose incremental changes. For the ComboBox to receive an update it would have to be assigned a new array.

Qt6.4 new list syntax

    property list<var> globalModel: ([
        { moduleId: "module1", power: 30, wavelength: 650 },
        { moduleId: "module2", power: 50, wavelength: 700 },
        { moduleId: "module3", wavelength: 500 },
        { moduleId: "module4", power: 80 },
        { moduleId: "module5", power: 80 },
        { moduleId: "module6" },
        { }
    ])

Whilst the above definition looks almost like the Array version, the type makes use of the Qt6 list syntax meaning that incremental changes to the list will now be reported.

yes, I use list solved this problem.

The role names in your model should be identical for all elements. From the documentation of ListElement:

The names used for roles must begin with a lower-case letter and
should be common to all elements in a given model.

As a solution, you can define special values for roles which do not apply for an element (e.g. -1):
ListElement { moduleId: "module1"; power: -1; wavelength: 650 }
ListElement { moduleId: "module2"; power: 50; wavelength: -1 }

Than you can check against this value:
console.log(globalModel.get(currentIndex).power === -1, globalModel.get(currentIndex).wavelength === -1)


Thanks bruh, but I have decided to give up using ListModel because JavaScript arrays can solve this problem. I always believe that this is because the Qt official did not improve the ListModel type, they did not provide such as hasOwnProperty() or "==undefined" or "property in obj" in JavaScript Object to determine the exist or absence of a property.
